# What is happening in this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, matrix-decomposition

I’m trying to understand the proof of Schur’s theorem, but I’m having trouble with one line. [image: the offending proof]
I don’t understand equation 1, and the authors I have looked at seem to think it’s obvious because none of them explain it. I even tried calculating an example but this did not help. What’s going on?

Comment: Since the first column of matrix $Q_1$ is an eigenvector $q$ for matrix $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ this means that $Aq=\lambda q$. By definition of matrix products, the first column of the product $AQ_1$ is going to be precisely $\lambda q$. Therefore, the first column of the product $Q_1^{\mathrm{T}}AQ_1$ is equal to the product between $Q_1^{\mathrm{T}}$ and $\lambda q$, the first column of $AQ_1$. Bearing in mind the orthogonality of matrix $Q_1$ can you see why $Q_1^{\mathrm{T}}q=e_1$? (my notation for the canonical basis vectors).

Answer (score 0):

The equation is equivalent to
$$AQ_1=Q_1\pmatrix{\lambda_1&*\\0&*}.$$
These matrices
will be the same if their first columns are the same. But as $q_1$ is the first
column of $Q_1$, their first columns are $Aq_1=\lambda q_1$.